# How to get rid of the gas estimation error in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, gas-price, gas-limit

```js
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require("ethers");
async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://172.25.160.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x556d125ef4d775230efcdc5ea8f993cbbf79cf4f33e763f447fd506923f016ed",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf-8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf-8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

This is the code i am trying to deploy. I am getting the private key and RPC server from **Ganache**.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

And this is my contract.

But i keep getting the following error:

```
<ref *1> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit from":"0x663a20EF5da385A29c85AF9e95899862be544434","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xd09dc300"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\abstract-signer\lib\index.js:365:47
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 6) {
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"id\":49,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\",\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at exactimate (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:182136)\",\"code\":-32000,\"name\":\"RuntimeError\",\"data\":{\"hash\":null,\"programCounter\":24,\"result\":\"0x\",\"reason\":null,\"message\":\"invalid opcode\"}}}", error={"code":-32000,"data":{"hash":null,"programCounter":24,"result":"0x","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}, 
      at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
      at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
      at C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:313:32
      at step (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"id":49,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at exactimate (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:182136)","code":-32000,"name":"RuntimeError","data":{"hash":null,"programCounter":24,"result":"0x","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}}',
    error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
        at getResult (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
        at processJsonFunc (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:356:22)
        at C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:288:46
        at step (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (C:\Users\LENOVO\Videos\Web3 Dev\hh-fcc\ethers-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      code: -32000,
      data: [Object]
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[,
    from: '0x663a20EF5da385A29c85AF9e95899862be544434',
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0xd09dc300', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    nonce: Promise { 0 },
    gasLimit: Promise { <rejected> [Circular *1] },
    chainId: Promise { 1337 }
  }
}
```

What should i do?? I tried to solve the problem but still can't get any solve. Waiting for your help. Thanks.

Comment: There might be an error in your contract constructor. Can you post you contract?

Comment: @MadeInDreams Here is it bro.

Comment: Where is your constructor?

Comment: @MadeInDreams Which constructor?? Actually it works in Remix IDE. But not in VsCode

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few thing wrong;

I believe your contract should have a constructor.

The constructor go before the first function declaration

```
constructor(){}
```

You also have some values that are not resolved because they are asynchronous

```
requestBody: '{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[,
    from: '0x663a20EF5da385A29c85AF9e95899862be544434',
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0xd09dc300', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    nonce: Promise { 0 },                             // <---
    gasLimit: Promise { <rejected> [Circular *1] },   // <---
    chainId: Promise { 1337 }                         // <---
```

You should use await in front of the functions that return these values so it will wait for it.